# Choose one off boot option in GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 : Windows dual boot. My USB keyboard is not responding in the boot menu so it is just timing out to my default OS (Ubuntu).  I am sure there is a way to make GRUB boot into a different option FROM the OS by touching a file somewhere before rebooting.  But I cannot remember how.  I am getting too many false positives on the Googles.  Can someone please remind me how to do this.  Cheers

[edit]  I am aware that I can change the default OS in my config but I would like to do it without changing it.  I am sure you can do it, or could .. maybe it was GRUB-legacy

Comment: Thanks but I would like to do it without changing my settings.

Comment: timeout huhh. which is the default loaded OS from your GRUB..?

Comment: Default is Ubuntu, which is fine.  I just need to boot to Win for one thing.  I rarely use it.

Comment: see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-tell-grub-i-want-to-reboot-into-windows-before-i-reboot

Comment: For the legacy mode, you didn't have to change the default, but did have to edit the configuration: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html - this is the same thing done in the U&L accepted answer.

Comment: Okay maybe I was remembering making grub boot to fsck. and not boot order.  cheers for the help

Comment: By changing my default boot in the config I can no longer boot back in to Ubuntu.  I am going to have to use a USB live boot to change it back.  I forgot why I needed it to be once off until I stuffed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to setup, I use a bluetooth keyboard and have used this method.

The tool you are looking for is grub-reboot with good instructions found [HERE](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubReboot)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the default option please try the below,

```
grep menuentry /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

After getting into it try the below,

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change the value to 0 for the already default existing OS as below,

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

After doing so save the changes and close the terminal.

Comment: By changing my default boot in the config I can no longer boot back in to Ubuntu. I am going to have to use a USB live boot to change it back. I forgot why I needed it to be once off until I stuffed up